# Why should blank threads consume 30% of CPU?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've wrote a c# console application.

After the boot, it starts 2 new threads which aren't doing anything heavy at all, why should this situation consume 30% of CPU?

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static DateTime LastPlayerRegistration;
    static List<Player> Players;
    static List<string> CommandsList = new List<string>
    {
        "GetPlayersNumber", "GetLastRegistration", "GetTimeElapsed", "NewPlayer"
    };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!File.Exists("Players.json")) File.Create("Players.json");
        Players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(File.ReadAllText("Players.json")) ?? new List<Player>();
        new Thread(PlayerInput).Start();
        new Thread(GeneralRoutines).Start();
    }

    static void PlayerInput()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] commandParameters = command.Split(' ');
            switch (commandParameters[0].ToLower())
            {
                case "getplayersnumber":
                    Console.WriteLine("There are " + Players.Count + " players registered!");
                    break;
                case "getlastregistration":
                    Console.WriteLine("Last registration happened at " + LastPlayerRegistration);
                    break;
                case "gettimeelapsed":
                    Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - LastPlayerRegistration) + " time elapsed from last registration");
                    break;
                case "newplayer":
                    if (commandParameters.Count() > 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandParameters[1]))
                    {
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        TimeSpan elapsed = (now - LastPlayerRegistration);
                        LastPlayerRegistration = now;
                        Players.Add(new Player(commandParameters[1], elapsed));
                        Console.WriteLine("Player " + commandParameters[1] + " created!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Player Name is missing!");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("'" + command + "' command is not defined.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void GeneralRoutines()
    {
        DateTime lastPlayersListSave = DateTime.Now;
        while (true)
        {
            if ((int)(DateTime.Now - lastPlayersListSave).Seconds >= 30)
            {
                File.WriteAllText("Players.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Players));
                Console.WriteLine("Players list saved!");
                lastPlayersListSave = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Player
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Elapsed { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Player(Guid id, string name, TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Elapsed = elapsed;
    }
    public Player(string name, TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Name = name;
        this.Elapsed = elapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that your program consumes 0% when you remove these threads?

Comment: Something like it

Comment: If you only got 256mb ram on your box 30% is possible not considered a high number.. Percentage is a relative number and useless without knowing the total available ram  :)

Comment: I have 6 GB of RAM ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it starts 2 new threads which aren't doing anything heavy at all

Uhm, I am pretty sure it says `while (true)` which will keep running that code until all CPU power is burned up and in that tight loop it keeps allocating (and eventually freeing) memory. There is nothing that stops that code to run as fast and as much as it can and thus to allocate massive amounts of memory in time.

You should delay the execution a bit. For example, you could use a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to delay the execution in case of 'no action' by a second.

Comment: I didn't expect while(true) without elaborations inside to consume this much

Comment: @MarcoSalerno: and what have you expected that the processor will be doing when it enters a `while(true) { donothing }` loop? You didnt ask him to sleep, wait, check if he's doing nothing, ask the OS if there is anythign else to do, and so on. It did what you asked him to: it ran the loop.

Comment: Obviously repeating the loop but i really tought it wasn't that heavy

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Indeed, it keeps execution that code. Even the repeated execution of the smallest statement will cause a 100% CPU load. It will just run more often than a longer statement.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine();` blocks the first thread, but the second one is spinning like crazy.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno See it as a hamburger contest: eat as much as you can in the time given. You will need less time for a small hamburger, but they will keep you occupied until the time is over. That is what your code does to the CPU, no matter how small.

Comment: now that reminds me that many years ago I was surprised by the same thing.. probably it's one of those things that every one has to see on their own :)

Comment: Exactly try writing Console.WriteLine in while(true) then you will know, it's not how heavy the code is, it's also how much break your code is giving to CPU

Comment: waitya all. He said RAM. Why RAM?

Comment: Yeah, added a line about that in my answer. Same problem though.

Comment: re "RAM" : it's most probably the fact that the loop runs very fast and does lots of String.Split which allcoates new strings and new arrays. GC will clean that up, but the rate of production is very fast

Comment: My bad wanted to say CPU

Comment: Anyway I did it cause i wanted to simulate a game's serverside. How are they running real time instructions if a while true is too heavy? Maybe a timer of 1 millisecond?

Comment: That's why you have framerates for UI, they do not process each nanosecond instead do it say 30 or 60 times a second and free the CPU for rest

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend ditching Spin-Waits completely. Saving a JSON to file every 30 seconds can easily be done using a Timer.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno: That's ..another story. Or many stories. There are couple of ways, and, seriously, spinning while(true) is one of them, and it is used somethimes. However, very often it's not dumb spinning all the time. If there's no tasks, servers sleep until they are notified about new tasks. Find&read about single-threaded vs multi-threaded vs 'asynchronous' processing of requests at serverside. You will find tons of materials and discussions.

Comment: By adding Thread.Sleep(1); in while, performances augmented a lot!

Comment: Actually that will be around 14ms, since the clock isn't that fast. But still, it will help indeed @MarcoSalerno